# How do I implement a function similar to HashMap::entry that doesn't consume the key?

Tags: generics, rust, traits

I am trying to implement something similar to `HashMap::entry` but allowing not consuming keys (See [this RFC](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/issues/690) with a similar purpose). Here is my code, modeled after the `Index` `impl` for `HashMap` (See [this](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/ops.rs.html#1911-1919) and [this](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/std/collections/hash/map.rs.html#1323-1334)).

```
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::hash::{Hash, BuildHasher};
use std::borrow::Borrow;

trait MapExt<Q: ?Sized, V> {
    fn get_or_insert(&mut self, key: &Q, value: V) -> &V;
}

impl<'a, Q: ?Sized, K, V, S> MapExt<&'a Q, V> for HashMap<K, V, S>
where
    K: Eq + Hash + Borrow<Q>,
    Q: Eq + Hash + ToOwned,
    S: BuildHasher,
{
    fn get_or_insert(&mut self, key: &Q, value: V) -> &V {
        if !self.contains_key(key) {
            self.insert(key.to_owned(), value);
        }
        self[key]
    }
}
```

This gives me the following error.

```
error[E0053]: method `get_or_insert` has an incompatible type for trait
  --> src/main.rs:15:42
   |
6  |         fn get_or_insert(&mut self, key: &Q, value: V) -> &V;
   |                                          -- type in trait
...
15 |         fn get_or_insert(&mut self, key: &Q, value: V) -> &V {
   |                                          ^^ expected reference, found type parameter
   |
   = note: expected type `fn(&mut std::collections::HashMap<K, V, S>, &&'a Q, V) -> &V`
              found type `fn(&mut std::collections::HashMap<K, V, S>, &Q, V) -> &V`
```

What is wrong here and how do I fix it?

Another problem that I think will arise is that the compiler does not know if `Q::Owned` is `K`. If it does, how do we handle it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm also a relative beginner, but from what I can see there are three issues:

```
MapExt<&'a Q, V>
```

should be

```
MapExt<Q, V>
```

otherwise you're changing the type of your trait to a reference.

```
Q: Eq + Hash + ToOwned,
```

should explicitly be

```
Q: Eq + Hash + ToOwned<Owned=K>,
```

so that it knows what type the `to_owned()` will return.

and

```
self[key]
```

should be

```
&self[key]
```

Comment: While this works, just beware that I can't tell you if there are better ways entirely since I'm learning too :P

Comment: Thanks, this combined with Shepmaster's answer cleared my understanding. One question: I did not know of the ToOwned<Owned=K> syntax -- when does it apply? Just for type traits? Any references will be helpful.

Comment: It is syntax to explicitly set the "associated type" of the `ToOwned` trait. If you look at https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/borrow/trait.ToOwned.html you can see that `Owned` is the type of the return value of `to_owned`.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem can be simplified to this:

```
trait Alpha<A> {
    fn alpha(&self, key: &A);
}

impl<'a, A> Alpha<&'a A> for () {
    fn alpha(&self, key: &'a A) {}
}
```

Basically, you are conflating the generic types. Using a separate letter makes it more clear:

```
impl<'a, B> Alpha<&'a B> for () {}
```

That is, the value for `Alpha`'s `A` is actually a `&'a B`. Then the trait says it takes a reference to that value. A valid implementation would be:

```
impl<'a, B> Alpha<&'a B> for () {
    fn alpha(&self, key: &&'a B) {}
}
```

Once you understand that, you can follow [loganfsmyth's points](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44855035/155423) to fix the remaining issues with the implementation.

Comment: Thanks, this helped.